# Parâmetros nulos em requisição JSF

Tags: primefaces, spring-mvc

Estou tentando mandar um parâmetro para um Spring bean mas não estou conseguindo, o map sempre está vazio. Segue abaixo meu código:

### XHTML:

```
<h:dataTable columns="2" 
    value="#{tipoMaquinaView.objectSelecionado.imagens}" var="anexoImg" >
    <p:column>
        <p:graphicImage value="#{downloadUploadAnexo.image}"  cache="FALSE">
            <f:param name="anexo_id" value="#{anexoImg.id}" />
        </p:graphicImage>
    </p:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

### Bean:

```
@Service
@RequestScoped
public class DownloadUploadAnexo implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private S3AnexoFacade s3AnexoFacade;

public StreamedContent getImage() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    } else {
        // Map abaixo sempre vazio
        Map<String, String> parameterMap = (Map<String, String>) context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String anexoID = parameterMap.get("anexo_id");

        if (anexoID == null) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }

        AnexoFacade anexoFacade = AppContext.getBean(AnexoFacade.class);    
        Anexo anexo = anexoFacade.buscarPorId(Long.valueOf(anexoID));

        InputStream stream = s3AnexoFacade.carregarArquivo(anexo.getCaminho());
        StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, anexo.getContentType(), anexo.getNome());     
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consegue verificar se `#{anexoImg.id}` não está vazio (e.g., imprimindo numa coluna)?

Comment: Sim, não está nulo, o valor é "1".

Comment: Ok, você não tem nenhum redirect ou algo assim no seu mapeamento né? Consegue aumentar o escopo para `session` para testar?

Comment: Outra coisa, tente colocar algo fixo para ver se chega do outro lado `<f:param name="anexo_id" value="2" />`

Comment: Então, o valor não chega do outro lado, fixo ou parseado na expressão, o "parameterMap" fica sempre vazio, como se não estivesse passando nenhum parâmetro. A situação foi a mesma alterando o escopo para "session" e "Application".

Comment: Uma coisa é que estou usando webflow em minha aplicação... Isso pode influenciar?

Comment: Pode sim Daniel. Te recomendo o seguinte; prepare um [**mvce**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (começando do zero). 99% de chance de que você encontre o passo que está furando tudo, se não encontrar pelo menos teremos um exemplo para trabalhar.